# Facebook always return error when authorizing my application

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to build a Facebook app, but everytime I click in authorize, I got an error.

In the code, I'm calling the Facebook API like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=MY_APP_ID
&display=popup
&redirect_uri=http://www.my-url.com/823/
&scope=user_about_me
```

But instead of authorizing the user, the browser redirect to this URL:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request

And I always get this error:

> SECURITY WARNING: Sharing the above URL with anyone is the same as
>   sharing your Facebook password with them - it will give them access to
>   your Facebook account. Despite what you may have been promised, you
>   will not receive cash, a gift card, or free airline tickets in
>   exchange for this URL.

My Facebook Settings Page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9S9m.png

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated! :)

**PS:** I just tried to change the "redirect_uri", from my site's URL(www.my-url.com/823/) for the canvas page(apps.facebook.com/my-app), and it works. 
But I want it to redirect to my site, not for the canvas page.
I had another application that was removed by Facebook last week. The domain I'm trying to use is the same of that old app removed. Is it possible that Facebook put the domain in a black list? Or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my app was removed by Facebook. When this happens, Facebook puts the site domain in a black list.
The solution was to redirect to the canvas page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace the « Website with Facebook Login » by the original URL? (Without the example path (823))

By the way, don't forget to complet app domains.

Comment: Just tried your both suggestions (setting the URL without path and writting the domain in the box) and didn't work. But thanks for the quick response!